# Set window size for Ursina Engine for Python

Tags: python, ursina

I'm using Ursina Engine to make a game. However I can't figure out a way how to set a specific size for the window. I need to figure this out, because I can't see part of it, because it's bigger than my screen.

I tried to use other posts on StackOverflow, but couldn't find anything. I also tried to use [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat), however it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

A google search led me to the documentation of the engine, where I found this:
https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference.html

As I understand it your main app class `Ursina()`, can accept various arguments, including amongst others 'size'.

Scrolling further down to the part named 'ASCIIEditor' there's an example usage:

```
app = Ursina(size=(1920,1080))
```

---

My experience with Ursina is limited to some introductory videos, so take this for what it is.